# IIS8 https refused to connect

Tags: ssl, iis, https

I have a windows 2012 server and have applied an SSL certificate following godaddy's guide:
https://uk.godaddy.com/help/iis-7-install-a-certificate-4801

I have applied the binding on the site in IIS however when I try to view the https site I get "refused to connect".

I have updated the firewall setting to allow port 443.
Any ideas?

Comment: How are you trying to access the site? Locally or through DNS? If you are trying through DNS, remove the hostname from the binding and try it with localhost first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to my site using a load balancer.
An additional load balancer for port 443 was required.

Anyone using rackspace will find this useful:

> To allow secure traffic you would need an additional load balancer
> allowing traffic on  port 443, with a shared VIP with the current one.
>
> https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/configure-a-load-balancer/